# Double folder icon in github

Tags: git, github

I have a repo I uploaded to Github and one of my folders 'Frontend' has a double folder icon that is greyed out and after some research, it seems like the .gitignore file inside of it was causing the problem. I deleted it and tried to reupload as a new repo and still having the issue. I just deleted the file from the folder, which I'm not sure if I had to delete this with a specific command line.

The folder consists of a Vue project, which the .gitignore file gets created automatically with Vue CLI but now I'm not sure where to head from here.

This folder is cannot be opened and viewed so I'm trying to fix that.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/LFRod4/django-vue

Comment: What exactly is your question? As written, it is difficult to determine what your problem is with regards to the icon.

Comment: You have a submodule; this is the representation for it.

Comment: @andrewFan apologies, at the moment that folder is not viewable. I want to be able to get into that folder from github for others to view

Comment: @ObsidianAge, unreachable submodule as there is no `.gitmodules` in the repo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a .gitmodules, then the folder (which cannot be opened) is most likely a gitlink: a reference to a nested Git repository.

Double-check locally on your PC/Mac the number of `.git/` subfolders you have: you should only have one.
If you have another nested under the root folder of your local repository, that would explain why add/commit/push also pushes that grey folder.